# Possible to have Storybook knobs toggle between string and null?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have a working setup of Storybook. However, I wonder if it's possible to have knobs that toggle between it's type (e.g. `string`) and `null`?

A naïve implementation would perhaps look something like this:

```
stories.add('with a button', () => (
  <MyComponent someString={text('Default', null)} />
));
```

Is it possible to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
<MyComponent someString={boolean('with text') ? text('Default', 'mytext') : null} />
```